# jQuery non-text input validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a Bootstrap table I obtained from [Tutorial Republic](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap-3&file=table-with-add-and-delete-row-feature).
It goes as such:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap Table with Add and Delete Row Feature</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
        color: #404E67;
        background: #F5F7FA;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    .table-wrapper {
        width: 700px;
        margin: 30px auto;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 20px;  
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    }
    .table-title {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        margin: 0 0 10px;
    }
    .table-title h2 {
        margin: 6px 0 0;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    .table-title .add-new {
        float: right;
        height: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-shadow: none;
        min-width: 100px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        line-height: 13px;
    }
    .table-title .add-new i {
        margin-right: 4px;
    }
    table.table {
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    table.table tr th, table.table tr td {
        border-color: #e9e9e9;
    }
    table.table th i {
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 0 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    table.table th:last-child {
        width: 100px;
    }
    table.table td a {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 5px;
        min-width: 24px;
    }    
    table.table td a.add {
        color: #27C46B;
    }
    table.table td a.edit {
        color: #FFC107;
    }
    table.table td a.delete {
        color: #E34724;
    }
    table.table td i {
        font-size: 19px;
    }
    table.table td a.add i {
        font-size: 24px;
        margin-right: -1px;
        position: relative;
        top: 3px;
    }    
    table.table .form-control {
        height: 32px;
        line-height: 32px;
        box-shadow: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
    table.table .form-control.error {
        border-color: #f50000;
    }
    table.table td .add {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    var actions = $("table td:last-child").html();
    // Append table with add row form on add new button click
    $(".add-new").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var index = $("table tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" id="department"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"></td>' +
            '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
        $("table").append(row);     
        $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    // Add row on add button click
    $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
        var empty = false;
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
        input.each(function(){
            if(!$(this).val()){
                $(this).addClass("error");
                empty = true;
            } else{
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
        if(!empty){
            input.each(function(){
                $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
            });         
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
        }       
    });
    // Edit row on edit button click
    $(document).on("click", ".edit", function(){        
        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function(){
            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        });     
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
    // Delete row on delete button click
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-wrapper">
            <div class="table-title">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8"><h2>Employee <b>Details</b></h2></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info add-new"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>John Doe</td>
                        <td>Administration</td>
                        <td>(171) 555-2222</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Peter Parker</td>
                        <td>Customer Service</td>
                        <td>(313) 555-5735</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fran Wilson</td>
                        <td>Human Resources</td>
                        <td>(503) 555-9931</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE03B;</i></a>
                            <a class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></a>
                            <a class="delete" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE872;</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>      
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>     
</body>
</html>
```

When you click "+ Add New" and try to add an empty record (leaving text fields empty), you are prevented from doing so and the textbox's border turns red.

However, when I add in a date field,

```
var row = '<tr>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="department" id="department"></td>' +     
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" id="date"></td>' +
        '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
```

I am still seemingly prevented from adding a record but the border of the date box does not turn red. The same thing happens for `<select>` dropdown menus.

I am looking at this bit here, the line `.find('input[type="text"]')`:

```
// Add row on add button click
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(){
    var empty = false;
    var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
    input.each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            $(this).addClass("error");
            empty = true;
        } else{
            $(this).removeClass("error");
        }
    });
    $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
    if(!empty){
        input.each(function(){
            $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
        });         
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

but I am afraid that is the extent of my abilities as a jQuery first-timer haha!

How do you modify the code to have both text type and non-text type inputs turn red their borders?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the [type="date"] control: `.find('input[type="text"], input[type="date"])`

Answer (score 0):

@fros
As you can see this jQuery validations are for input field and then it.

```
var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
input.each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
        $(this).addClass("error");
        empty = true;
    } else{
        $(this).removeClass("error");
    }
});
```

Just add date field validation below this like,

```
 var input_date = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="date"]');
```

and same error class for red mark add/remove goes here.

Answer (score 0):

add class uniq in all input on tr

```
var row = '<tr>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control example" name="name" id="name"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control example" name="department" id="department"></td>' +     
    '<td><input type="text" class="form-control example" name="phone" id="phone"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="date" class="form-control example" name="date" id="date"></td>' +
    '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
'</tr>';
```

and try this

```
var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('.example');
```

thanks